# Kubernetes: Weave network not installing

Tags: linux, nodes, kubernetes, weave

When I am running this command for weave network, it is showing this error.

```
[root@ts ~]# kubectl apply -f https://git.io/weave-kube
error validating "https://git.io/weave-kube": error validating data: [unexpected type: object, unexpected type: object, unexpected type: object, unexpected type: object]; if you choose to ignore these errors, turn validation off with --validate=false
```

How to resolve this?

Comment: Also getting this after using --validate=false                                                                           
`[root@ts ~]# kubectl apply -f https://git.io/weave-kube --validate=false
Error from server: error when retrieving current configuration of:
&{0xc2082cbb80 0xc20800eaf0 kube-system weave-net https://git.io/weave-kube 0xc2083643c0 0xc2083fc5a0 }
from server for: "https://git.io/weave-kube": daemonsets.extensions "weave-net" not found`

Comment: What version of Kubernetes were you running?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@verma_neeraj,

1. Does this still and consistently happen to you?
2. Which Kubernetes version are you using?
3. What happens if you run `curl https://git.io/weave-kube`?

I can confirm the YAML file available at https://git.io/weave-kube successfully configures the Weave Net daemonset under Kubernetes versions `1.5.+`, but I have not tried other versions.

Anticipating an issue related to Kubernetes versions, note that there is work being done to support multiple Kubernetes versions, see [these](https://github.com/weaveworks/launch-generator/pull/55) [two](https://github.com/weaveworks/launch-generator/issues/68) GitHub issues.
This should be available in the coming weeks.

(Disclosure: I work for Weaveworks)